# audio.play() works in Chrome but not Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-audio

I know there are questions similar to this on this site that have been answered, but I haven't found any that fix this issue which is why I'm making a post.

Here is what I have tried:

- Listening for events "canplay", "loadedmetadata", "canplaythrough"
- Doing audio.load() on initialization
- Setting audio.preload to "auto"
- Testing on Chrome (it works perfectly in this browser!)
- Appending the audio element to document.body on initialization

When I try to play() without the eventListener (which also doesn't work), the console says: `Unhandled Promise Rejection: NotSupportedError: The operation is not supported.`

Am I missing something?

The code:

```
var AUDIO = {
    create: function(name, file, type) {
        AUDIO.library[name] = {};
        AUDIO.library[name].type = type;
        AUDIO.library[name].audio = new Audio();
        AUDIO.library[name].audio.preload = "auto";
        if (type=="music") {
            AUDIO.library[name].audio.loop = true;
        }
        AUDIO.library[name].audio.src = file;
        AUDIO.library[name].audio.load();
    },
    play: function(name, fadeout_playing) {
        if (fadeout_playing) {
            for (let i=0; i<AUDIO.playing.length; i++) {
                let n = AUDIO.playing[i];
                AUDIO.fadeout(n);
            }
        }

        let a = AUDIO.library[name].audio;
        a.currentTime = 0;
        a.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function() {
            console.log("you are listening to: "+ name);
            AUDIO.playing.push(name);
            a.play();
        }, false);
    },
    fadeout: function(name) {
        var sound = AUDIO.library[name].audio;

        var fade = setInterval(function() {
            if (sound.volume >= 0.1) {
                sound.volume -= 0.1;
                sound.volume = sound.volume.toFixed(1);
            }
            if (sound.volume <= 0) {
                sound.volume = 0;
                let index = AUDIO.playing.indexOf(name);
                AUDIO.playing.splice(index, 1);
                clearInterval(fade);
            }
        }, 200);
    },
    library: {},
    playing: [],
};
```

```
AUDIO.create("act1", "music/chillelectric.mp3", "music");

//this runs when i click a button
function setup() {
    ...
    AUDIO.play("act1");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what version of safari are you using? Is it mobile browser?

Comment: i'm on the new m1-based macbook, so to be honest, i'm not sure. could it mean it loads the same browser as on ios?

Comment: Why not just make a normal audio tag? Why do you need a struct `{}` to hold internal functions... basically what problem does your code setup solve that cannot be solved with a standard audio element controlled by JS?

Comment: hahaha yeah that's definitely the better idea. i think my original intention was to be more organized, but it doesn't seem much more effective to do it this way. anyway, normal audio tags don't work either. it's weird because it works fine on the w3schools.com javascript demo. i'm starting to think this is a problem outside of the code i've posted, in which case, i'm not sure how to get any help on this.